# What type of recursion is a return statement with an "OR"?

Tags: java, recursion, big-o, pseudocode

Here's my pseudocode for a recursive program that moves a circle either right or left of an array. I'm trying figure out the complexity (which I think is n, the size of the array A, or could it be 2^n since it can either return left or right?).

I'm also trying to figure out what kind of recursion this is, since it has an OR in the last return statement but nowhere can I find information on this.

```
 Boolean rightWing (int circle, Array A, List<int> checkerList)

Integer lastPlace equals A.length - 1

If circle equals lastPlace then // base case for recursion
    Return true

If circle < 0 then
    Return false

If circle > lastPlace then
    Return false

// impossible case
If checkerList contains (circle) returns True then
    Return false

checkerList.add(circle) // add the circle to the list for the checker if it's an impossible case

Integer moveRight equals circle + A[circle] 
Integer moveLeft equals circle - A[circle]

Return rightWing ( moveRight, A, checkerList) or rightWing(moveLeft, A, checkerList)
```

Comment: Define 'kind of recursion'. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your algorithm is correct but from what you said i think you will check each element of your array once so O(n) with n = sizeof(A) is correct.

The kind of recusive call you're looking for is tail-recursive or non-tail-recursive. 
[What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion)